# How do I get the area code from phone numbers using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a column with 1 to 3 digits.
For example:

1. (342) 342-9324
2. (1) 234-3424
3. (04) 234-7744 etc

But I am not sure how to write the query. I use

`SUBSTRING(x, 2, 3)`

where x is name of column, but I only get 3 digits, anyone have any ideas to extract digits in brackets that could be 1, 2 or 3 digits? This is done using sql server. Also this table has more than 5 million rows of phone numbers

Answer (score 2):

If area code is within `()`, some simple string functions should do.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Phone] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('(342) 342-9324')
,('(1) 234-3424')
,('(04) 234-7744')
 
Select * 
      ,AreaCode = replace(left(Phone,charindex(')',Phone+')')-1),'(','')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Phone           AreaCode
(342) 342-9324  342
(1) 234-3424    1
(04) 234-7744   04
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply, can you briefly explain what you are doing in the sql code you wrote above? Also how did you come up with the code "AreaCode = replace(left(Phone,charindex(')',Phone+')')-1),'(','')"?

Comment: @john43 First we find the charindex of ')' in Phone+')'.   The +')' is just a fail-safe in case there are none.   Let's assume that was the 5th position, we take minus 1 leaving us with 4.   We then take the left 4 characters of the string.  Finally we replace the leading ( with an empty string.